# Why the operator $A$ is closed in Lumer-Phillips? (Pazy's book)

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

**Question**. Why $A$ is a closed operator?

My attempt: I will show that $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}$ is an bounded operator. First, we note that $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}:X\to D(A)$. Now, let $u\in X$. Asumming that $\text{Range}(\lambda_0-A)=X,\, u=(\lambda_0-A)v$ some $v\in D(A)$. Then

\begin{align}
\left\|(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}u\right\|&=\left\| (\lambda_0-A)^{-1}(\lambda_0-A)v\right\|\\
&=\left\|v\right\|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\left\|(\lambda_0-A)v\right\| \text{ (disipativity condition)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left\|u\right\|
\end{align}

By the other hand, the operator $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}$ is closed. Let $u_n\subset X$ with $u_n\to u (u\in X), (\lambda_0-A)^{-1}u_n\to v,\, v\in D(A)$. Then
\begin{align}
\left\|v-(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}u\right\|\leq \left\|v-(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}u_n\right\|+\left\|(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}(u_n-u)\right\|
\end{align}
By the assumptions, $\left\|v-(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}u_n\right\|\to 0$ and $\left\|(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}(u_n-u)\right\|\leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\left\|u_n-u\right\|\to 0$ (because $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}$ is bounded).

Therefore, $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}$ is an closed operator.

Why the closedness of the operator $(\lambda_0-A)^{-1}$ implies the closedness of $\lambda_0-A$? Why $A$ is a closed operator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof that $(\lambda_0I-A)^{-1}$ is bounded and, consequently, closed is fine. To show that $\lambda_0I-A$ (and thus $A$) is closed one can argue as follows:

To say that $(\lambda_0I-A)^{-1}$ is a closed operator is equivalent to saying $${\rm Gr}((\lambda_0I-A)^{-1})=\{(v,(\lambda_0I-A)^{-1}v):v\in X\}$$ is a closed subset of $X\times X$. Therefore---as $F:X\times X\to X\times X$, $F(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ is a continuous bijection---the following set is also closed:
\begin{align*}
\big\{((\lambda_0I-A)^{-1}v,v):v\in X\big\}&=
\big\{((\lambda_0I-A)^{-1}(\lambda_0I-A)x,(\lambda_0I-A)x):x\in D(A)\big\}\\
&=\big\{(x,(\lambda_0I-A)x):x\in D(A)\big\}={\rm Gr}(\lambda_0I-A)\,.
\end{align*}
Hence $\lambda_0I-A$ is a closed operator. But this implies that $A$ is closed which can be seen as follows.

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X$ be given such that $x_n\to x$ and $Ax_n\to y$. Thus $(\lambda_0I-A)x_n=\lambda_0x_n-Ax_n=\lambda_0x-y$. As $\lambda_0I-A$ is closed this implies $x\in D(A)$ and $$(\lambda_0I-A)x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lambda_0x_n-Ax_n)=\lambda_0\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}Ax_n=\lambda_0x-y\,.$$
Obviously the latter is equivalent to $Ax=y$ which---together with $x\in D(A)$ as shown above---lets us conclude that $A$ is closed.